# .Net MVC / Web API Attribute Routing triggers Download

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, routes

Having added WebApi to an MVC 5 project (.aspx AND Razor engines) I am trying to add Attribute Routing however whenever I add this line:

```
// Web API routes
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

to the WebApiConfig file it produces the bizarre behaviour that the initial page load (MVC route of account/login) results in the browser treating the request as a ***download*** and the browser opens the download dialog box!

To me this would typically be the result of a bad file extension but in this environment there is clearly something wrong with the routing but for the life of me I can't figure out what I'm missing.

Without the MapHttpAttributeRoutes line an Ajax call to the WebApi controller's "Post" action  does work.

I'll mention that the Ajax call is via Angular however there is no angular functionality embedded in the pages related to the /Account/Login routing

I am posting the related controllers and App_Start/Config files and Web.Config files below.

Any idea would be greatly appreciated, I'm hoping to avoid having to recreate the project from scratch :-(

Thanks!

My Api Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;
using mvc4.SecretService.com.Models;

namespace mvc4.SecretService.com.Controllers
{
     [RoutePrefix("api/santas")]
     public class SantasController : ApiController
     {

           private SeniorsSecretServiceEntities db = new SeniorsSecretServiceEntities();

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("list")]
    public IEnumerable<sssSantaProfile> List()
    {
        var profiles = db.sssSantaProfiles.AsEnumerable();
        return profiles;

    }
    ......
 }
```

WebApiConfig file :

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        // THIS CAUSES THE ISSUE
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        //config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
        //config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }
}
```

The RouteConfig file looks like this :

```
 public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {

        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And the MVC Account Controller looks like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Transactions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet;
using Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth;
using WebMatrix.WebData;
using mvc4.SecretService.com.Filters;
using mvc4.SecretService.com.Models;

namespace mvc4.SecretService.com.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [InitializeSimpleMembership]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {

        public AccountController()
            : base()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Seniors Secret Service";

         }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.Action= "Log In";
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
         }

         [HttpPost]
         [AllowAnonymous]
         [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
         public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
         {
               if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
              {
                  return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
              }

              // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
              ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
              return View(model);
        }
        .....
    }
```

ROOT Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
        <sectionGroup name="dotNetOpenAuth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.DotNetOpenAuthSection, DotNetOpenAuth.Core">
         <section name="oauth" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OAuthElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
          <section name="openid" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.OpenIdElement, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
           <section name="messaging" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.MessagingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
           <section name="reporting" type="DotNetOpenAuth.Configuration.ReportingElement, DotNetOpenAuth.Core" requirePermission="false" allowLocation="true" />
     </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<appSettings>
<add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
<add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <add assembly="WebMatrix.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add assembly="WebMatrix.WebData, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>
</pages>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="simple">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider,WebMatrix.WebData" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership defaultProvider="simple">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider,WebMatrix.WebData" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" />
  </providers>
</membership>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.Core" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet" publicKeyToken="2780ccd10d57b246" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.3.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135.21930" newVersion="1.6.5135.21930" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="itextsharp" publicKeyToken="8354ae6d2174ddca" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.5.6.0" newVersion="5.5.6.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.OData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Data.Edm" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Spatial" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.6.4.0" newVersion="5.6.4.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebMatrix.Data" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebMatrix.WebData" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Antlr3.Runtime" publicKeyToken="eb42632606e9261f" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.5.0.2" newVersion="3.5.0.2" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
<legacyHMACWarning enabled="0" />
</runtime>
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
</entityFramework>
<dotNetOpenAuth>
<openid>
  <relyingParty>
    <security requireSsl="false">
    </security>
    <behaviors>
      <add type="DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.Behaviors.AXFetchAsSregTransform, DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty" />
    </behaviors>
  </relyingParty>
</openid>
<messaging>
  <untrustedWebRequest>
    <whitelistHosts>
    </whitelistHosts>
  </untrustedWebRequest>
</messaging>
<reporting enabled="true" />
</dotNetOpenAuth>
<uri>
<idn enabled="All" />
<iriParsing enabled="true" />
</uri>
<system.net>
<defaultProxy enabled="true" />
<settings>
</settings>
</system.net>
</configuration>
```

/Views Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
        <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>

<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
</appSettings>

<system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>

    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <controls>
            <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
        </controls>
    </pages>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
        <remove name="Session" />
        <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
        <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the exact same behavior when I added the same line of code `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` to the WebApiConfig file in my MVC 5 project. The problem was resolved by making a change in the Global.asax file. As noted under the heading Enabling Attribute Routing in this article on adding [attribute routing in ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#enable) you can check for the line:

```
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```

in Global.asax and replace it with:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

Once I made this change in Global.asax my MVC 5 project ran properly without the bizarre display of the downloads dialog. As noted in the article I had migrated my MVC 5 project from a Web API 1 template. I started using Web API 2 in my project by adding the Web API 2 NuGet package.

Here is the text from the article:

**Note: Migrating From Web API 1**

Prior to Web API 2, the Web API project templates generated code like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // WARNING - Not compatible with attribute routing.
    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
}
```

If attribute routing is enabled, this code will throw an exception. If you upgrade an existing Web API project to use attribute routing, make sure to update this configuration code to the following:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // Pass a delegate to the Configure method.
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that - I ended up reconstructing the VS project from scratch but the result was essentially what you have above, so, marked as answer :-)

Comment: I pretty much had an identical issue, and replacing WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration); with GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register); sorted the issue for me.